# using DES/3DES with python

Tags: python, cryptography, 3des

what is the best module /package in python to use des /3des for encryption /decryption.
could someone provide example to encrypt data with des/3des on python.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**pyDes**](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html) can be used for both, DES and 3DES. Sample usage:

```
from pyDes import *

data = "Please encrypt my data"
k = des("DESCRYPT", CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
d = k.encrypt(data)
print "Encrypted: %r" % d
print "Decrypted: %r" % k.decrypt(d)
assert k.decrypt(d, padmode=PAD_PKCS5) == data
```

---

An alternative is the [**Chillkat Python Encryption Library**](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/python-encryption.asp) which supports a lot of encryption algorithms (including DES & 3DES), but it is **not** free. Sample usage:

```
crypt.put_CryptAlgorithm("des")
crypt.put_CipherMode("cbc")
crypt.put_KeyLength(64)
crypt.put_PaddingScheme(0)
crypt.put_EncodingMode("hex")
ivHex = "0001020304050607"
crypt.SetEncodedIV(ivHex,"hex")
keyHex = "0001020304050607"
crypt.SetEncodedKey(keyHex,"hex")
encStr = crypt.encryptStringENC("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
print encStr
decStr = crypt.decryptStringENC(encStr)
print decStr
```

---

Anyway, I hope that you are aware that neither DES nor 3DES are considered paritcularly safe nowadays, there are **many better alternatives** (AES in the first place if you want to stick to standards, or Twofish, Blowfish, etc...)

Comment: print "Encrypted: %r" % d  ---> why no parentheses?

Comment: @CaTx because its Python 2.x

Comment: I'm getting ... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyDes'

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) Python wrapper for [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).  It has the advantage of being fast (as fast as OpenSSL), but the disadvantage of the documentation being limited.

Here is the example from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541763/how-to-3des-encrypt-in-python-using-the-m2crypto-wrapper/3552505#3552505) to ["How to 3DES encrypt in Python using the M2Crypto wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541763/how-to-3des-encrypt-in-python-using-the-m2crypto-wrapper)"

```
with open(keyfile, 'rb') as f:
    key = f.read()
encrypt = 1
cipher = Cipher(alg='des_ede3_ecb', key=key, op=encrypt, iv='\0'*16)
ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext)
ciphertext += cipher.final()
```

Comment: The M2Crypto link you have is dead.