# How to 3DES encrypt in Python using the M2Crypto wrapper?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, m2crypto, 3des

I have a working test of a hardware device that uses RSA encryption, in Python using M2Crypto.  Now I need to test a similar device that uses 3DES encryption.  But I can't figure out how to use M2Crypto to do triple DES encryption.

I know it should be possible from [this chart](http://mikeivanov.com/pc/python-crypto.pdf).  But unfortunately [the documentation of M2Crypto](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/) I've found is sketchy.  (The [homepage](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) at http://chandlerproject.org/ seems to be gone, along with Chandler.)

I've searched for 3DES and "OpenSSL API" and found some hard to grok C code for decrypting which makes it look like I need to use M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher.  But I haven't found any examples of using it for DES.  The closest I've found is [this blog post on using it for AES encryption](http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/aes-encryption-in-python-with-m2crypto/).  It looks like I just need to figure out the correct arguments to `M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher.__init__()`.  I'll keep digging, but I thought it worth posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
with open(keyfile, 'rb') as f:
    key = f.read()
encrypt = 1
cipher = Cipher(alg='des_ede3_ecb', key=key, op=encrypt, iv='\0'*16)
ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext)
ciphertext += cipher.final()
```

Note the keyfile is a 24-byte (binary) file with parity set as sometimes required for DES.

Note also that the iv argument is (I believe) ignored when using 'des_ede3_ecb', but I couldn't pass `None`.)

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_evp.py). There is reference for the following DES ciphers : 'des_ede_ecb', 'des_ede_cbc', 'des_ede_cfb', 'des_ede_ofb', 'des_ede3_ecb', 'des_ede3_cbc', 'des_ede3_cfb', 'des_ede3_ofb'.

The homepage seems to be [here](http://wiki.osafoundation.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) now.

Comment: I didn't think to look at the tests.  Thanks!