# ODI | Decrypt a file Using DES

Tags: jython, des

I have a file encrypted using DES algorithm. I want to decrypt the file in ODI (Oracle data integrator) by writing procedure in Jython. I have explored the built-in functions, but I am unable to find one for decryption. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python based libraries.

pyDes: http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html

pycrypto: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/

[using DES/3DES with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435283/using-des-3des-with-python)